# Why does this while loop work?

Tags: java, while-loop

Why does this work:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int i;
int beerBottles = 100;

//Asks the user for the number of beer bottles on the wall
System.out.println("How many bottles of beer are on the wall?");

while (!keyboard.hasNextInt())
{
System.out.println("Make sure you enter an integer.");
keyboard.next();
}
//Sets beerBottles to the user entered value
beerBottles = keyboard.nextInt();
```

I stumbled on this while trying to make sure that the user input was an integer without using try/catch and I have no idea why it works or if something is horrendously wrong that I'm missing. It seems to work perfectly, which would be great, but I don't understand why the "Make sure you enter an integer" text doesn't always show. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
keyboard.hasNextInt()
```

blocks until it has input to examine. When it does, it returns `true` if it finds an integer value, and false otherwise.

Therefore, if you enter an integer value, the `while` loop is never entered. If you didn't, the `keyboard.next()` inside the loop clears the value you entered to let you try again.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't enter a valid integer value, the Scanner.hasNextInt() does not return a true. Since the negation of hasNextInt() is being checked at the while condition - it prints "Make sure you enter an integer." until an Integer value is entered.

Hope this helps 
[Scanner.hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)

Comment: A suggestion: I think that some additional information would make a better answer... I think that just providing a link is better suited for a comment