# Validating Scanner input in Java

Tags: java, validation, input

How do I stop my program from crashing when a non numeric value is entered? I'm aware of kbd.hasNextLong, but I'm unsure how to implement it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552811/why-does-this-while-loop-work/19552848#comment29014062_19552848

Comment: Could you post some code for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can validate it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean end = false;
    long value;
    while (end == false) {
        try {
            value = input.nextLong();
            end = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please input the right LONG value!");
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `input.nextLine()` in catch-statement. If you type in some non-int text, it jumps into catch (cause Integer couldnt be read in nextInt), it printline message and then it goes again. But the value typed does NOT dissapiered so it crashes again even if you dont do anything.

The `input.nextLine()` "flushes" what you put in.

Using hasNextLong is other way (however I would prefer throwing an exception, because it IS an exception) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean end = false;
    long value;

    while (end == false)  {
        if (input.hasNextLong()) {
            value = input.nextLong();
            end = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("input the LONG value!");
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this using .hasNextLong instead?

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to use hasNextLong instead of try-catch statement?

Comment: This is for an assignment, and we're not supposed to use methods that haven't been taught in class

Comment: Added hasNextLong statement, remember to mark me as accepted :).

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to use exceptions.

```
int value;
do {
    System.out.print("Type a number: ");
    try {
        value = kbd.nextInt();
        break;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong kind of input!");
        kbd.nextLine();
    }
}
while(true);
```